# How to grant BigQuery job creation permission?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-iam

how can I grant the correct permission so that I can run queries with Python sdk on BigQuery?

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/MY_PROJ/queries?alt=json returned "Access Denied: Project db-cm-dev: The user joyce-something1@MY_PROJ.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission in project MY_PROJ.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the [IAM page](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam?_ga=2.190150504.-2132222021.1538157385) of your project, by granting the service account mentioned in the error message the role of [bigquery.jobUser](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#roles) or higher, you will be able to create jobs.